# Trying to find factorial and display it in a new activity. Crash on startup

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make this app where I'm taking a value from the main activity sending it to the second one where I generate it's factorial and display it. I'm probably doing something wrong, here is the code of the mainactivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

EditText n = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_num);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.ok_button:
            int val = Integer.parseInt(n.getText().toString());
            bundle.putInt("nval",val);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Answer.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

    }
}
}
```

This is the second class:

```
public class Answer extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    int val = bundle.getInt("nval");
    int x = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<val; i++)
    {
        x =(x*i);
    }

    String txt = Integer.toString(x);
    textView.setText(txt);
}
```

XML for main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.manan.fibbo.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_num"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:hint="@string/fibnum"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ok_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
    android:text="@string/but_txt"
    />
```

XML for second activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.manan.fibbo.Answer">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
```

I'm probably doing a million things the wrong way here, this is just a mockup/test code. Please excuse my shitty programming practices.

Here is the thing I got from debug:

https://pastebin.com/19QtVLZD

Comment: When you are getting a crash, it is generally a good idea to post the Stacktrace, so that people can think about what is wrong without reading the whole code :)

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: Is there snippet of the output when the crash occurs?

Comment: Ok let me google how to do that and I'll edit it in right away, sorry I'm a bit new at this.

Comment: Ok I've added the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have this initialization here:

```
EditText n = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_num);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
```

First create the variable as

```
private EditText n;
private Bundle bundle
```

then **onCreate** do this

```
 n = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_num);
 bundle = new Bundle();
```

Comment: That did it! thanks a lot!! I was stupid enough to not realize I can declare the variables outside the onCreate method, I had it that way at first but then I realized I can't use those outside the onCreate method so I declared them outside. Should've done your way to begin with. Thanks again.

Comment: happy to help @MananAdhvaryu

Answer (score 0):

Replace MainActivity.java with code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_num);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.ok_button:
            int val = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
            bundle.putInt("nval",val);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Answer.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

    }
}
```

As we have to use findViewById mehod inside the onCreate() method and again you have to set onClickListener on button or else use onClick:method_name in XML for
the button click listener.

Comment: Ahh that's right, I was wondering why clicking the button was doing nothing, I forgot to setOnClickListener. I should probably get some sleep with all these shitty mistakes I'm making.

Comment: i think in answer.java, to find the factorial of number you have to use i<=val inside loop